# New Flutter Project on Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, mobile

Can you guys tell me what all these different projects means?

[New Flutter Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNoZp.png)

Because I can't find the documentation anywhere
So if you can find the reference it will help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Flutter Application: A fully-functional standalone Flutter application.
2. Flutter Plugin: A plugin is a kind of bridge that you develop between a native feature like camera API in Android and iOS.
3. Flutter Package: A package is a flutter application written solely using Dart. It doesn't have much to do with the Native functionalities.
4. Flutter Module: A module is a set of functionalities that you want to use in your app. It is a custom code that does a specific task but can be used for other apps in the future. So, you keep it handy. In other words, this module can be integrated in other apps too.